# Pyodbc stored procedure with params not updating table

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am using python 3.9 with a pyodbc connection to call a **SQL Server** stored procedure with two parameters.

This is the code I am using:

```
connectionString = buildConnection() # build connection
cursor = connectionString.cursor() # Create cursor
command = """exec [D7Ignite].[Service].[spInsertImgSearchHitResults] @RequestId = ?, @ImageInfo = ?"""
values = (requestid, data)
cursor.execute(command, (values))
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

`requestid` is simply an integer number, but `data` is defined as follows (list of json):

`[{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}]`

The stored procedure I am trying to run is supposed to `insert` data into a table, and it works perfectly fine when executed from Management Studio. When running the code above I notice there are no errors but data is *not* inserted into the table.

To help me debug, I printed the query preview:

`exec [D7Ignite].[Service].[spInsertImgSearchHitResults] @RequestId = 1693, @ImageInfo = [{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}]`

Pasting this **exact** line into SQL Server runs the stored procedure with no problem, and data is properly inserted.

I have enabled `autocommit = True` when setting up the connection and other CRUD commands work perfectly fine with pyodbc.

Is there anything I'm overlooking? Or is pyodbc simply not processing my query properly? If so, are there any other ways to run Stored Procedures from Python?

Comment: When you paste that exact line into SSMS and execute it the value actually passed in to `@ImageInfo` is `{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}`. Do the square brackets `[]` make a difference when sent from Python as the string `'[{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}]'`?

Comment: Good observation. Yes, the square brackets `[]` are necessary because the stored procedure uses them as markers to define when to start and stop processing json info.

Comment: "I notice there are no errors" - Does your stored procedure begin with `SET NOCOUNT ON;` …?

Comment: Yes, `SET NOCOUNT` is ON

Comment: Does `type(data)` return `<class 'str'>`, or `<class 'list'>` ?

Comment: There is no way in the world you could execute `exec [D7Ignite].[Service].[spInsertImgSearchHitResults] @RequestId = 1693, @ImageInfo = [{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}]` in SSMS with no errors. You would need apostrophes not square brackets `exec [D7Ignite].[Service].[spInsertImgSearchHitResults] @RequestId = 1693, @ImageInfo = '{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}'` I suggest you stringify the JSON before passing it to SQL Server

Comment: @Charlieface - I thought so, too, but I tried it in SSMS against SQL Server 2019 and it did work. The result is the same as if the square brackets were single quotes. TBH, I don't know if that is documented behaviour, but it does not throw an error.

Comment: To be clear, I did already try adding apostrophes to the command, passing
`exec [D7Ignite].[Service].[spInsertImgSearchHitResults] @RequestId = 1693, @ImageInfo = '[{"ImageSignatureId":"27833", "SimilarityPercentage":"1.0"}]'` through the python script. No luck yet.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes. `type(data)` returns `<class 'str'>`.

Comment: Looks like that's a compatibility thing and should probably be avoided. [The docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) *"If the value of a parameter is an object name, character string, or qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks. ..... If you pass a single word that does not begin with `@` and that's not enclosed in quotation marks ...... the word is treated as an `nvarchar` string, in spite of the missing quotation marks."*

Comment: Either way you want to use parameters, not injected strings, so the way you are doing it now with `?` and no quotes is correct, except that you need to stringify `data` before you pass it. Try `values = (request, JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/n5V98J4P) works for me.